# Получение категорий с количеством товаров в них MySql

Tags: php, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT category.*, COUNT(1) AS count 
FROM category 
JOIN goods ON category.id = goods.category 
WHERE category.status != '0' 
  AND goods.status != '0' 
GROUP BY category.id
```

Данный пример найдет все записи из таблицы `category` и к ним прибавит кол-во найденных товаров из таблицы `goods` соответствующей категории. Но в категориях есть и подкатегории `parent`.

Как правильно написать запрос, который выбирал бы записи из `category` даже если в `goods` не найдено товаров из этой категории? То есть в например категория **мебель** - главная (id = 3, parent = 0), категория **кухонная мебель** - подкатегория (id = 4, parent = 3). При этом, товары находится могут только в подкатегориях. Товары у которых `category = 4` не будет вовсе, а категрию все равно нужно вывести для формирования меню.
Старался описать понятно, в принципе это стандартная логика, просто не нашел решения в сети.

Comment: используйте `left join`. только остается вопрос что должен при этом посчитать count. он засчитает одну запись и в случае если в goods ничего не будет и если там будет одна запись. так что вероятно надо что то вроде `count(goods.category)`

Comment: @Mike ни `left join` ни `count(goods.category)` ничего не дает к сожалению, пробовал до этого и сейчас попробовал.

Comment: А вы `AND goods.status != '0'` случайно не забыли в ON `left join` перенести ? Ведь если вы в where оставите это условие  и записи в goods не будет, то status будет NULL, а условие NULL!=0 даст ложь и запись не будет найдена.

Comment: Сделал так: `SELECT category.*, COUNT(goods.category) AS count FROM category LEFT JOIN goods ON category.id = goods.category WHERE category.status != '0' AND goods.status != '0' GROUP BY category.id` или не так надо?

Comment: перенесите условие, про которое я сказал выше. нельзя просто так проверять поля правой для left join таблицы в where

Comment: Условие по goods.status должно находиться в секции ON, а не в секции WHERE. Иначе LEFT JOIN превращается в скрытый INNER JOIN. И нулевые записи не будут выведены. `SELECT category.*, COUNT(goods.category) AS count FROM category LEFT JOIN goods ON category.id = goods.category AND goods.status WHERE category.status GROUP BY category.id`

Comment: @Akina то что нужно, почти. Жаль что в родительской категории подсчет идет 0 если товаров конкретно кв ней нет. Нельзя ли подсчитать кол-во товаров в подкатегории и вывести значение в родительскую?

Comment: Укажите точную версию MySQL.

Comment: А уровень подкатегорий только один ? Структура позволяет любую вложенность ... А в MySQL до версии 8.0 рекурсии не было и сбор чего либо по иерархии вложенности такое извращение, что лучше и не планировать ...

Comment: @Akina MySql 5.7
Mike то есть лучше сменить версию MySql ? В OpenServer нет версии больше чем 5.7

Comment: Вы так и не написали количество чего все таки хотите получить. может все не так уж из плохо. Тем более что меню вы возможно будете собирать рекурсией на php. Но лично я бы сказал, что если вы действительно хотите работать с рекурсивными данными с неизвестной вложенностью в самой БД, то вам стоит брать другую СУБД (например postgresql).

Comment: @Mike Мне помог шестой ответ. Я использую кеш, поэтому получение данных в принципе уже подходит любым способом. Но тот ответ мне реально помог.